# Trying to create multiple choice questions based on text

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers

How can I ask meaningful multiple-choice questions based on inputted text (I don't want generate the questions myself)

In the code, I figured out if certain keywords were nouns, verbs, adverbs or adjectives but I ended up writing the questions myself

Using transformers, here's what I have developed

```
from transformers import T5ForConditionalGeneration, T5Tokenizer
import nltk
import random

# Load the T5 model and tokenizer
model_name = 't5-base'
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

while True:
    # Ask the user for input text
    input_text = input("Enter the input text (or 'exit' to quit): ")

    if input_text.lower() == 'exit':
        break

    # Tokenize the input text
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(input_text)

    # Remove stopwords
    stop_words = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))
    filtered_words = [word for word in words if word.lower() not in stop_words]

    # Extract key terms (nouns and proper nouns)
    key_terms = [word for word, pos in nltk.pos_tag(filtered_words) if pos in ['NN', 'NNS', 'NNP', 'NNPS']]

    # Shuffle the key terms
    random.shuffle(key_terms)

    # Generate 5 multiple-choice questions
    questions = []
    for term in key_terms[:5]:  # Limit to 5 key terms
        options = random.sample(key_terms, 4)
        options.append(term)
        random.shuffle(options)
        correct_answer = options.index(term)

        # Identify the part of speech
        pos = nltk.pos_tag([term])[0][1]

        if pos.startswith('N'):
            question = f"What is the noun '{term}'?"
        elif pos.startswith('V'):
            question = f"How important is the verb '{term}'?"
        elif pos.startswith('R'):
            question = f"What is the adverb describing '{term}'?"
        elif pos.startswith('J'):
            question = f"What is the adjective describing '{term}'?"
        else:
            question = f"What is '{term}'?"

        questions.append((question, options, correct_answer))

    # Print the generated questions
    for i, (question, options, correct_answer) in enumerate(questions):
        print(f"Question {i + 1}: {question}")
        for j, option in enumerate(options):
            print(f"   {chr(65 + j)}. {option}")
        print(f"Correct Answer: {chr(65 + correct_answer)}\n")

# Exiting the loop
print("Goodbye!")
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. Do you want to use T5 to create multiple-choice questions for you?

Comment: yes, except that I don't get questions related to a text

Answer (score 0):

Your task may be achieved using a [Question Generation model](https://paperswithcode.com/task/question-generation).

Some good implementations:

- [Varifocal Question Generation for Fact-checking](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.12400) (Vlachos, et al. 2022)
- [T5 for Question Generation](https://huggingface.co/valhalla/t5-base-e2e-qg) [HF]
- [Learning to Generate Questions by Recovering Answer-containing Sentences](https://openreview.net/forum?id=PRr_3HPakQ) (Back, et al. 2020)